# ValueError in Keras: How could I get the model fitted?

Tags: python-3.x, neural-network, keras

I am trying to fit my model  (neural networks) using keras but I got ValueError error.

import keras

```
from keras.models import Sequential

from keras.layers import Dense


classificador_rede_neural = Sequential()


# # Camadas Ocultas e de Saída

# camadas ocultas = (entradas + saídas)/2 #estimando o numero de neurônios em camada oculta
# 
# temos:len(train.columns) - 1   atributos previsores
# 
# 1 classe


#len(train.columns)


camadas_ocultas = round(len(train.columns)/2)



print(camadas_ocultas)


classificador_rede_neural.add(Dense(units=camadas_ocultas, activation='relu',input_dim =len(train.columns) ))#primeira camada


classificador_rede_neural.add(Dense(units=camadas_ocultas, activation='relu' ))#segunda camada


classificador_rede_neural.add(Dense(units=1, activation='sigmoid' ))#camada de saída. a saída é binária, logo units=1
```

classificador_rede_neural.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='binary_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])

```
classificador_rede_neural.fit(X_train2,y_train2,batch_size=10,epochs =100)
```

I am getting the error:

```
 ValueError: Please provide as model inputs either a single array or a list of arrays. You passed: x=              sload        dload  spkts  dpkts  swin  dwin  smean  dmean  \
    0      1.803636e+08     0.000000      2      0     0     0    248      0   
    1      8.810000e+08     0.000000      2      0     0     0    881      0   
    2      8.544000e+08     0.000000      2      0     0     0    534      0   
    3      6.000000e+08     0.000000      2      0     0     0    450      0   
    4      8.504000e+08     0.000000      2      0     0     0   1063      0   
    5      1.045333e+09     0.000000      2      0     0     0    392      0   
    6      1.306667e+09     0.000000      2      0     0     0    980      0   
    7      1.977143e+08     0.000000      2      0     0     0    692      0   

[82332 rows x 22 columns]
```

How could I fit the model? What is wrong with my data?

The complete code > https://pastebin.com/jE7erEJs

Comment: How do `X_train2` and `y_train2` look like?

Comment: @Colonder: https://ibb.co/jsCmqJ

Comment: @Colonder: https://ibb.co/juDbqJ

Comment: @Colonder: https://pastebin.com/KpZZ69Ar

Comment: The error is confusing, because you should provide Numpy array not list!!!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I think the problem is that you passed to your model an entire pandas dataset together with the columns headers and an index column. In order to train your model on your data, convert it to a numpy array first with `X_train2.values` and `y_train2.values` since a Keras model accepts as input a numpy array and not a pandas dataset

Similar question
[Pandas DataFrame and Keras](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43876770/pandas-dataframe-and-keras)

Documentation on Keras' Sequential model
https://keras.io/models/sequential/

**Edit to answer the comments**
Don't convert each column separately, this is pointless. Assuming that you have a general dataset `df` with a column called `labels` what you have to do is

```
labels = df.pop("labels")
model.fit(x=df.values, y=labels.values)
```

Comment: How could I convert it?

Comment: Look at the answer. Either use `X_train2.values` or `X_train2.as_matrix()`

Comment: X_train2,y_train2 =train.drop('label',axis=1),train['label']

X_test2,y_test2 =test,classe1_test

Comment: I am trying to use your answer but I am stuck! Could you look at the complete code > pastebin.com/jE7erEJs

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173281/discussion-between-colonder-and-laurinda-souza).