# How to process a pandas dataframe for a recurrent neural network with keras?

Tags: python, keras, recurrent-neural-network, tensor

I have a dataset. I need to build a recurrent neural network with (attached image). I'm having issues with turning the inputs into a 3D tensor that I can use in keras. The dataset consists of 2820 rows and 2 columns

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cMKPq.png)

This is what my code looks like to split the data into training, validation, and test sets, and to turn into the x inputs into a 3D tensor:

```
n_steps = 50
X_train, y_train = df[:1500, :n_steps], df[:1500, -1]
X_valid, y_valid = df[1500:2000, :n_steps], df[1500:2000, -1]
X_test, y_test = df[2000:, :n_steps], df[2000:, -1]
print(X_train.shape, y_train.shape)
```

However, I am getting an error

```
TypeError: '(slice(None, 1500, None), slice(None, 50, None))' is an invalid key
```

when I run this code. How can I do that?

Comment: If you have 3 columns you cannot access column from 0 to 50. That's what you are doing when you use`,:n_steps` in `df[:1500, :n_steps]`. You need first `reshape` your 2D data to a 3D tensor

Comment: do you know how I would reshape this from 2D to 3D?

Comment: First convert the df to a numpy array with `df.values` and then do something like `np.reshape(-1, 2820, 3)` don't know where you are going to input this data. This migth help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/51552829/1207193